# Run interactive command line exe using c#

Tags: c#

I can run a command line process using `process.start()`.
I can provide input using standard input. After that  when the process demands user input again, how can my program know and pass the input to that exe?

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/process-handling-net) covers many of the intricacies of working with .NET processes, particularly around working with input and output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's an [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) that sounds similar to what you need, using `Process.StandardInput` and a `StreamWriter`.

```
        Process sortProcess;
        sortProcess = new Process();
        sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Sort.exe";

        // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Redirect the standard output of the sort command.  
        // This stream is read asynchronously using an event handler.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");

        // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
        sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream
        // is used synchronously.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        sortProcess.Start();

        // Use a stream writer to synchronously write the sort input.
        StreamWriter sortStreamWriter = sortProcess.StandardInput;

        // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
        sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ready to sort up to 50 lines of text");
        String inputText;
        int numInputLines = 0;
        do 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a text line (or press the Enter key to stop):");

            inputText = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText))
            {
                numInputLines ++;
                sortStreamWriter.WriteLine(inputText);
            }
        }
```

hope that helps

Comment: thanks again. but this is specific to sort.exe
i m generating exe at run time for every user. i dont know which program he will type.

Comment: I think you can use "cmd.exe" instead of the executable they chose. It's a hack, but it might get the job done

Comment: Dear robert can u plz explain how to use cmd.exe for my problem

Comment: `sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";` might do the trick

Comment: I updated [my stupid-simple .NET library project](https://github.com/kenny-evitt/ExecuteCommandLineProgram) for running command line programs to include support for 'standard-input input' based on your answer – thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly I think you should be able to do this by redirecting the Standard Input/Output using [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) and [RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx).

The WinSCP project has a C# sample for how to communicate with it using this way. You can find it here: [SFTP file transfers in .NET](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet) (though this sample only collects the output without using it at all, but the technique should be the same.)

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i tried it. but the process demanding user input is not predefined. the scenario is like
1. I want to design online compliler for c#
2. i can build the program using code dom n cretae exe
3. now i want to run that exe through c#
4. user can write any type of program which needs user input at diff stage.
hope u understood whole scenario

Comment: @rajshades: I would have thought that would be similar though, just that instead of sending in all the commands in one go, you'd send in a command, read the output, send in the next command etc. Though I've not tested this. As a general note though, if you're creating the exe, can't you try to give it some better way of communicating with it (WCF, TCP/IP sockects, name pipes etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look up IPC. As robert showed above, the `Process` class in .NET will help you. But specifically for your problem (how to know when to write data): You can't. Not generically.

If you know the required input (e.g. "yyy"), you can supply it in the `STDIN` of the created process. You don't have to wait for the program to request this information: It will just read from `STDIN` when it wants data.

If you need to process the programs output to decide what to write to `STDIN`, try reading the processes `STDOUT`. You might run into problems with flushing, though...