# C# UI automated testing - Does anyone succeeded to capture the command prompt window object?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, cmd, automation

I have an `UI` automated test developed with White. One of the cases needs to open `cmd` and write some commands. The problem is when I input the first command. 
I tried something like:

```
Process.Start("CMD.EXE");

///Thread.Sleep(2000);

SendKeys.SendWait(command);
```

The problem is that `sendkeys` starts to input before the windows is opened, and trims the command, skipping first characters (depending on window appearance moment). It works with a sleep, but I'm trying to avoid such practices.
In order to avoid this I would insert a timer to wait for the window to be visible. So my questions:

- Can this window be captured, so I can wait for it?

OR

- Any other way to send the command?

Comment: I'm not sure you're supposed to use SendKeys to interact with the command prompt. Have you investigated using StandardInput?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308500/run-interactive-command-line-exe-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this special case ,you could execute the cmd  to run your commands as args, i mean, avoid sendKeys and execute the cmd like this : `Process.Start("CMD.EXE", "/c echo hello world");`

note that /c will execute the cmd and exit while /k execute the cmd and return to the CMD prompt.

Comment: This was my resolution too. Thanks!