# Automating interactive command line process from C#

Tags: c#, process, console

I have an *.exe that has an interactive text command interface which I want to automate from C#.

The (1) is the C # result, and the (2) is the result of directly using *.exe.
(latter miss "connect ok!" & "download successfully!")

(1)
connect ok!
cable detect ok!
download successfully!

(2)
cable detect ok!

I don’t know how to make the result of C # the same as the (2), below is my code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = ex.exe; 
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("prj_project open " + "...../bin/store//*****Water.ldf");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("pgr_project open " + "...../bin/store/imp11/imp11.xcf");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("pgr_program run");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

p.WaitForExit();

var str = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var str2 = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.WriteLine(str2);
p.Close();
```

For some reason, I want to mask out some places, hope not to cause your confusion.

If you can help me solve this problem, thank you very much.

It drives me crazy...It took me almost fifteen hours to solve...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please pay attention to the tags you select.

Comment: Here's [some example code for WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet) (link found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308668/243245)), which looks like it's the same as you're doing already. I would try adding a Thread.Sleep for a few seconds after starting the process but before writing the commands, in case the process clears its input buffer before waiting for command line input. Can you make the same process work with inputs from `<` or `|` on the console?

Comment: Actually are you sure it didn't work? The 'Connected to Lattice Cable Server' is almost the last thing in the right-hand output, after all the commands have run. The process might detect that it's not connected to a TTY and be less verbose.

Comment: I tried it, the left side can operate my device, but I can't return the result I want

Comment: What specifically is the result you want? Do you mean the same text output on the right, i.e. the device works but you don't get the same text output, or that the device doesn't behave properly?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t view the message for a few days, "the device works but you don't get the same text output" ←it's my problem!